# I dont quite understand why i am getting this error concerning vectors

Tags: c++

My program takes two input files, one of which is a list of commands. Each line of the file is a new command, so i want to parse this file into an array. I was told to use a vector as it dynamically grows which would eliminate the need for a function to count the number of lines in the file and then use that data to create an array.

Here is what my program is right now:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;


//Prototypes
int parseLines(ifstream& countfile);


vector<string> parseLines(ifstream& countfile)
//counts number of lines in file passed to function
{
   string line;
   vector<string> lines;
   int numberOfLines;

   //reads through each line until end of file putting each line in a sperate entry of the vector
   while(getline(countfile, line))
   {
       lines.push_back(line);
   }

   return lines;
}


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

        int i;

    if(argc != 3) cout << "Usage: calendar.out datafile inputfile";

    //Create input streams to both files
    ifstream apptsfp;
    ifstream inputfp;

    //Open streams to both files
    apptsfp.open(argv[1]);
    inputfp.open(argv[2]);

    if(!inputfp.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "failed to open input file\n";
        return 1;
    }

        vector<string> inputVector;
        vector<string> apptsVector;

    inputVector = parseLines(inputfp);

        for(i=0; i<= inputVector.size(); i++)
        {
        cout << "Input " << i << ": " << inputVector[i] << endl;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

And i am getting this long error when i compile and i dont quite understand it:

```
$ g++ calendar.cpp
calendar.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > parseLines(std::ifstream&)’:
calendar.cpp:17:46: error: new declaration ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > parseLines(std::ifstream&)’
calendar.cpp:14:5: error: ambiguates old declaration ‘int parseLines(std::ifstream&)’
calendar.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
calendar.cpp:58:37: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘inputVector = parseLines((* & inputfp))’
calendar.cpp:58:37: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/vector:70:0,
                 from calendar.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/vector.tcc:161:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >]
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/vector.tcc:161:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&’
```

I feel like i don't quite understand how to use vectors.

Comment: You can't overload based on return type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prototype

```
int parseLines(ifstream& countfile);
```

Realization

```
vector<string> parseLines(ifstream& countfile)
```

Return types differs.

Comment: ayup. its official, i'm dumb.

Comment: @Aaron did you understand the compiler error you got? It is much better if you understand that instead of understanding what actually went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Not the question asked but another error is

```
   for (i = 0; i <= inputVector.size(); i++)
```

should be

```
   for (i = 0; i < inputVector.size(); i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `int parseLines(ifstream& countfile);` function declaration. There is a conflict with later `vector<string> parseLines(ifstream& countfile)` definition:

Change first with:

```
vector<string> parseLines(ifstream& countfile);
```

Besides, as this function definition is before its use, you can delete its declaration.